# What will Happen If I dont Upgrade 11.10 to 12.04 ? Can I still be able to use Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10

I do not need an Upgrade. I can check things using live cd. Can I keep Ubuntu 11.10 forever ?

Comment: Are you going to get the [other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134535/is-there-a-listing-of-all-new-known-ubuntu-12-04-related-problems-and-their-solu) deleted?

Comment: Do you want me to delete it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  This chart: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases shows that 11.10 will be supported until April 2013

Eventually it will not be supported and then will not get bug fixes and the like.  If you never do any installs or upgrades again you'll be ok, but with most software updating pretty frequently these days, it's not a good choice long-term.

Also if someone discovered a security bug it may not be fixed or fixed quickly in an old version, potentially compromising your data.

Security, fixes and bug patches aside there's no reason it will stop working,

i.e. there is no expiry date to **actually using it.**

Comment: What about the ppas? I acuualy seeking the information whether I will be able to install new softwares or not after the support date expires ?

Answer (score 0):

11.10 will be supported until spring of 2013, so you should upgrade by then.  12.04 will be supported until spring of 2017.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "check things using live cd?"

In any case, Ubuntu 11.10 won't stop working, but in one year, Canonical will stop supporting it with security updates.  After that, you could conceivably update things like the kernel, but it will become difficult when things bread as a result.

You can simply keep using it, but if you connect to the internet, it may be irresponsible; if someone discovers an exploit, and breaks into your system, they could disrupt many users using your system until your internet provider disconnects you.

Comment: I mean new features. I can check new features of Ubuntu 12.04 using a live cd. There are lots of similarities in working and looks of 12.04 &  11.10

Comment: Oh, I see.  I'd recommend that you don't worry about it for the next 9 months, then when 11.10 is a few months away from its end of life date, you can look more closely.  Perhaps there will be changes or fixes by then.  That's what I'm doing for now - 11.10 works fine for me, 12.04 has some minor problems.

Answer (score 0):

Curious Apprentice: You are wrong in my opinion, you DO need an upgrade to stay current with new software, but as others have said, TO BE SECURE.

The easiest way to do this is keep your beloved 11.10 going, but to partition your hard disc (if it isn't already) and load Ubuntu 12.04 as a FRESH install on to a new clean partition. You will now have a choice of booting into 11.10 or 12.04. Now, you can transfer your personal files to the new install at your leisure, and install applications in 12.04 to bring it up to the standard you require. You will still have 11.10 to fall back on during this process. Better still, create yet another partition and keep your personal files on that, totally separate from any OS.